# Postgres generate_series for each unique row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to do something like this

```
key | series
____________
  1 |   1
  1 |   2
  2 |   1
  3 |   1
  3 |   2
  3 |   3
  4 |   1
  4 |   2
```

How do I go about generating a series for each unique key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a window function `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT key, 
       row_number() over (partition by key) series
FROM table1
;
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a6301/4

Comment: So awesome. Simple and elegant. Worked perfectly for me.